# How can I disable roles in a Windows Azure project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I have a solution with 5 Azure roles and the Azure solution is set as the startup project. When I run the solution 5 internet explorer windows popup, 1 for each role. I want to only run the role on which I'm working.

If I comment out the roles in the servicedefinition.csdef file VS2010 complains when the roles are referenced from within the various .cscfg files.

If I comment out the role in the currently executing .cscfg file, VS2010 complains about the reference from within the .csdef file.

Right clicking the Azure project and selecting Manage Roles does not allow me to select which roles are actually executed.

What's the best way of disabling roles that I'm not interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to just disable the endpoint starting up in the browser.

Right click the role under the Azure project - properties and scroll down to:

[image: Start Up Action]

And uncheck the endpoint for the roles you're not currently busy with.